# Command with combined behavior of both `sort -n -u -k` and `uniq -c`

Tags: linux, sorting, command-line, uniq

I have a multi-field text file. I'd like to have a command that would combine both the behavior of both `sort -n -u -k` and `uniq -c` - that is, sort the file on a certain key filed and the provide the number of duplicates prepended or postponed to the original line. At the moment, I either sort on the certain key and obtain the first of the duplicated lines without the number of duplicates with `sort -n -u -k` or count the number of duplicates with `uniq -c` by extracting the key field.

Can you suggest a command with both behavior implemented?

An example of the file (the key column can be any of the specified):

```
       4549              1       22656489       63452157           3235           1116            612         532275        6009800         534075        6012488         477375        5995844         533175        6011144        8388615            236
       4549              2       22656489       63452158           3214           1116            613         532275        6009825         534075        6012488         477375        5995831         533175        6011157        8388615            236
       4549              3       22656489       63452159           3193           1116            614         532275        6009850         534075        6012488         477375        5995819         533175        6011169        8388615            236
       4549              4       22656489       63452160           3173           1116            615         532275        6009875         534075        6012488         477375        5995806         533175        6011182        8388615            235
       4549              5       22656489       63452161           3152           1116            616         532275        6009900         534075        6012488         477375        5995794         533175        6011194        8388615            235
       4549              6       22656489       63452162           3131           1116            617         532275        6009925         534075        6012488         477375        5995781         533175        6011207        8388615            235
       4549              7       22656489       63452163           3111           1116            618         532275        6009950         534075        6012488         477375        5995769         533175        6011219        8388615            235
       4549              8       22656489       63452164           3091           1116            619         532275        6009975         534075        6012488         477375        5995756         533175        6011232        8388615            234
       4549              9       22656489       63452165           3070           1116            620         532275        6010000         534075        6012488         477375        5995744         533175        6011244        8388615            234
       4549             10       22656489       63452166           3050           1116            621         532275        6010025         534075        6012488         477375        5995731         533175        6011257        8388615            234
       4549             11       22656489       63452167           3030           1116            622         532275        6010050         534075        6012488         477375        5995719         533175        6011269        8388615            234
```

Comment: Does a pipe (`sort -n -k | uniq -c`) not suit your needs?

Comment: No, because `uniq -c` doesn't honor the uniquness of the certain key field, but compares the entire line with entire others.

Comment: uniq does have a _limited_ ability to ignore unwanted fields (the `-f` and `-s` options).  If that is not enough, you could (if it meets your other requirements) put a `cut` or `awk` command between `sort` and `uniq` to reorder the fields into a form that `uniq` can handle.

Comment: That's the problem - I need both of the wanted behaviors of `sort` and `uniq` - that is, keeping the whole line intact but using the certain field as a key *and* counting the number of duplicates on that key.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could be more specific:  What does your input data look like, how many fields, what is the field separator, which field do you want to sort on, etc.?

Comment: I've updated the question with an example of the several lines from the file (there are millions of lines in the file). These lines should be grouped by several certain columns, yeilding a one-per-key resulting line with multiplicity of duplicates counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**decorate-sort-undecorate**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), you can append to the data the fields you want to base your processing in, do the processing, and remove the extra fields. E.g to sort on fields 17 and 5:

```
awk '{print $0 OFS $17 OFS $5}' test_s  | sort -n -k18 -k19  | uniq -c -f17 | awk '{NF=18;print}'
```

You first append the key fields, then `sort` and `uniq` on them, and then only preserve the  count added by `uniq` and the original fields.

Answer (score 1):

As I currently understand it, you want to specify one or more columns to use as a key and obtain a result with each output line showing the multiplicity for that key.  In that case, suppose your data is in a file called "data" and we want column 17 as the key:

```
$ awk '{print $17}' data  | sort -n | uniq -c
  4 234
  4 235
  3 236
```

Thus, the value of 236 appears in column 17 a total of 3 times in your test data.  Or, suppose you wanted columns 6, 8, 1, and 3 as the key (and in that order):

```
$ awk '{print $6,$8,$1,$3}' data  | sort -n | uniq -c
 11 1116 532275 4549 22656489
```

For this key, all 11 lines are dups.

This approach has three steps.  First, we have `awk` select the columns you want in the order you want.  Second, `sort -n` sorts them numerically on the keys.  Lastly, `uniq` counts duplicates.

UPDATE: Suppose, as above, we want to use columns 6, 8, 1, and 3 as the key but, as per your comment, we want keep one of the original lines.  In this case we instruct awk to put the original 17 columns before the key, we tell sort to sort on the key (columns 18+) and then we instruct uniq to ignore those first 17 columns:

```
awk '{print $0,$6,$8,$1,$3}' data  | sort -k18 -n | uniq -f 17 -c
```

For your sample data, this results in:

```
     11        4549             10       22656489       63452166           3050           1116            621         532275        6010025         534075        6012488         477375        5995731         533175        6011257        8388615            234 1116 532275 4549 22656489
```

If you only want the original 17 columns printed, then we can use perl to show just the first 17 columns and crop off the key:

```
awk '{print $0,$6,$8,$1,$3}' data  | sort -k18 -n | uniq -f 17 -c | perl -nle '@a=split;print join " ", @a[0..17]'
```

which results in:

```
11 4549 10 22656489 63452166 3050 1116 621 532275 6010025 534075 6012488 477375 5995731 533175 6011257 8388615 234
```

Comment: Your understanding is almost correct, except that I don't want to lose information from one of the original lines. In your answer, everything except the key value from the original line is lost, but I'd like to count the lines that are duplicates according to the key, keeping the line that represents the whole duplicated group.